# scraping real estate data from public county records / gis

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrape, uipath

I'd like to scrape data from the following website: http://maps2.roktech.net/durhamnc_gomaps4/

In a separate spreadsheet on my computer, I have a list of parcel IDs, corresponding to various properties in the county.

Here's what needs to happen:
1. First, copy and paste parcel ID (from a separate spreadsheet) into the search box, to search by parcel. 
2. Then, copy and paste all the columns of data that show up associated with that parcel ID, and paste it into the spreadsheet.

And that's it! it sounds pretty simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried using UI path but I'm not experienced with the software.

How could I go about doing this? How difficult is this to do?

Thanks so much for any help or assistance.

Ryan

Comment: The question is too broad - What language/program are you planning to use? You didn't tag any...

Comment: If you want to do this by yourself, first you need some weeks to learn uipath -> https://academy.uipath.com/learn

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for general help or please do this and that. You need to start with something. So get to know UiPath. Try scraping on your own. And when you still have trouble come back and ask. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please watch the following training video on how to scrape data using UIPATH.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uipath/uipath_studio_data_scraping_and_screen_scraping.htm

It is highly recommended to go through the free UiPath RPA Academy training videos that will quickly put you in the know

https://academy.uipath.com/learn/course/internal/view/elearning/372/level-1-foundation-training-revamped-20182

Comment: why to try to scrape data that you can download one time? first get familiar with the environment that you and your bot will work with and if you need materials about this you can find them here: https://academy.uipath.com/learn/lp/39/BusinessAnalyst

Answer (score -2):

You don't need uipath for this job

1. Go to the site
2. zoom out
3. click "select options"
4. select the whole area 
   5.A table with "1000 results" will appear on the same line where "1000 results" is written there are 4 buttons the last one is "**export to EXCEL**" - click it and you will have the whole data in one table and then you can filter this table

Comment: This doesnt answer his specific question on UiPath. Granted that is a viable solution, however it does not answer the specifics to his query.

Comment: Yes this is question for UiPath but it is so far away from a specific one. My advise would save ryan's time and efforts